# Android PWA not installing as WebAPK

Tags: android, progressive-web-apps

I have a PWA that passes the Chrome Lighthouse PWA tests and properly installs as a WebAPK on an Asus Xenpad tablet (Android 7.0, Chrome 75).  My goal was to get deep linking (opening the PWA with a URL elsewhere on the tablet) and that works great on this tablet.

I have a newer Lenovo Tab 4 8 tablet running Android 8.1.0 and Chrome 79 that won't install this PWA as a WebAPK.  It's seems to just install it as a basic PWA so deep linking doesn't work.  The PWA will open in standalone mode OK but it doesn't actually get "installed" like a WebAPK.  It seems my site is fine since it installs on 1 tablet and passes the Lighthouse tests.  Does anyone know why this newer tablet won't work?  I've been all through the settings and don't see anything obvious.  I've done a factory reset on this device, too.

Thanks

Comment: Using an HTTPS URL?

Comment: yes I'm using HTTPS

Comment: If possible, have a few other new android users test. Then you can narrow it down to that device/browser combination.

Comment: After some more testing this seems to be a Chrome issue.  I upgraded the working tablet from Chrome 75 to 79 and now it's broken, too.  Anyone know of a bug with Chrome that was introduced between 75 and 79 with PWAs?

Comment: Currently investigating a similar issue and my suspicion is that if you don't have an Google account associated with the tablet or are logged out of the Google play store that PWAs don't install correctly and revert to Chrome shortcuts

Comment: @MikeMarshall I can confirm that.

Comment: @MikeMarshall I know it's been a long time but I've been testing this and can confirm as well. Have you seen any documentation or workarounds for this?